# Is it possible to make radial control that can be select with controller L or R

Tags: windows, user-interface, uwp, controls, gamecontroller

I could not pinpoint to a specific keyword of it. But,

I was looking for a control in UWP app that supports down to version 14393

A radial control like in lots of games that can be select with L or R on a game controller. (eg. Grand Theft Auto V weapon selection)

I found something similar which is Dial controller, but it only works with Surface Dial

Comment: I'm afraid you may need to write your own, try to get it on Community toolkit if you do. And the formal name is Pie menu. 

Nice to see you ToonWK, funny the connections you find online.

Comment: … what a coincidence  ._.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to make radial control that can be select with controller L or R

You could refer [RadialGauge XAML Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/radialgauge) that comes from Community Tool Kit.

```
<controls:RadialGauge x:Name="RadialGaugeControl" Column="1" Value="70" Minimum="0" 
    Maximum="180" TickSpacing="20" ScaleWidth="26" Unit="Units" TickBrush="Gainsboro"
    ScaleTickBrush="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    NeedleWidth="5" TickLength="18">
</controls:RadialGauge>
```

[image]

For the source code you could refer [this](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/tree/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/RadialGauge).